Ising Model - Infinite volume correlation inequality to finite volume
In a recent paper (Corollary 1.6) the inequality $\langle \sigma_0 \rangle_{\Lambda_n, \beta}^+ - \langle \sigma_0 \rangle_{\Lambda_n, \beta}^- \le C_1 e^{-C_2N}$ was stated, where $\langle \cdot \rangle_{\Lambda_n, \beta}$ is the expectation with respect to the Ising-Model on $\Lambda_n := ([-N,N] \cap \mathbb{Z})^d$. This was stated to be a classical result and I worked through a more modern (and publicly available) version here, where Theorem 2.1 (3) should be what we need: $\langle \sigma_0 \sigma_x \rangle_\beta^+ \le e^{-C d(0,x)}$. As far as I can see, the original paper should be equivalent.
If this property was valid for the setting above, then we could pick $x$ on the boundary, resulting in $\sigma_0 \sigma_x = \sigma_0$ (for positive boundary conditions), yielding the claimed inequality. However this paper uses free boundary conditions and especially this property was proven in the infinite volume $V$ (or rather the weak limit $\Lambda \to V$).
I'm having trouble understanding how to obtain the above inequality from this. Do I need the DLR property? Or can I make an estimate? $\langle \sigma_0 \rangle_{\Lambda_n, \beta} \le \langle \sigma_0 \rangle_{\beta}$ should be true for free boundary conditions, but not for positive ones.
